# Unable to search a record in list in list

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv

With the help of some contributors from StackOverflow, I wrote a small program to read in a CSV file so that I could search a record or multiple records. The program works and is tested but when it reads from a CSV file, it does not work. I try to search a record in the list of list and it fails to find anything. Could someone help please?

```
import csv

#Read in CSV file
datafile = open('nba_2Records.csv', 'r')
datareader = csv.reader(datafile, delimiter=';')
data = []
for row in datareader:
    data.append(row)    

print(f"Data = {data}")

# Search Value
search = 'Boston Celtics'

for sublist in data:

    print(f"sublist : {sublist}")
    if search in sublist:
        print("Found it!" + str(sublist))
    else:
        print("Not found")


=============================================================================================================================
Data = [['Name,Team,Number,Position,Age,Height,Weight,College,Salary'], ['Avery Bradley,Boston      Celtics,0,PG,25,2-Jun,180,Texas,7730337'], ['Jae Crowder,Boston Celtics,99,SF,25,6-Jun,235,Marquette,6796117']]
sublist : ['Name,Team,Number,Position,Age,Height,Weight,College,Salary']
Not found
sublist : ['Avery Bradley,Boston Celtics,0,PG,25,2-Jun,180,Texas,7730337']
Not found
sublist : ['Jae Crowder,Boston Celtics,99,SF,25,6-Jun,235,Marquette,6796117']
Not found
```

Answer (score 1):

your sublist is array with only one string item, when using `string in list` it will search for list item equal to the string not for list item containing in the string.

If you always have one element on sublist the you can do this

```py
if search in sublist[0]:
        print("Found it!" + str(sublist))
```

Else you have to add another loop

```py
for item in sublist:
    if search in item:
        print("Found it!" + str(item))
```

Comment: Hi Dev, thank you. It is working now. One question, once selected based on “Boston Celtics” on the 2 rows, how can I add “7730337” and “6796117“ from the 2 selected rows.

Comment: How do you know my sublist is an array? I thought my sublist is a list.

Comment: I also mean list, to extract number after coma in the row you can use sublist[0].split(",")[-1] which splits the string at comma and take last part

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the delimiter as `,`

**Ex:**

```
search = 'Boston Celtics'

with open('nba_2Records.csv') as datafile:
    datareader = csv.reader(datafile, delimiter=',')
    next(datareader) #Skip header
    for row in datareader:
        if search in row:
            print("Found it! " + row)
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, I tested your codes and the only change is to string the row. I have a question for you, how do you collect the selected output and then perform computation like it was a Spreadsheet table.

Comment: what computation ?

Comment: Add computation on columns that have numeric values in it. How can I manipulate the list as though it is like a Excel table where I can pick rows and columns?